# Generic XML Serializer deserialize generically

Tags: c#, xml, generics, serialization

I have a simple serialization class for writing my custom objects to XML on disk:

```
   public class ReaderWriter
    {
        public static void StoreObjectInformationInFile<T>(T objectToBeWritten, string passedDestinationFileName)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objectToBeWritten.GetType());
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(passedDestinationFileName);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToBeWritten);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to add a Generic Deserialization function to this Class that does the same thing but in reverse? something like this:

```
        public static <T> GetObjectInformationFromFile<T>(string passedDestinationFileName)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the prototype of generic deserialization method

```
public static T GetObjectInformationFromFile<T>(string passedDestinationFileName)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using(var stream = new StreamReader(passedDestinationFileName))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```